# django: Testing POST-based views with json objects

Tags: ajax, django, json, unit-testing

I have a django application with several views that accept json objects via POST requests. The json objects are medium-complex with a few layers of nesting, so I'm using the json library to parse raw_post_data, as shown here:

```
def handle_ajax_call(request):
    post_json = json.loads(request.raw_post_data)

    ... (do stuff with json query)
```

Next, I want to write tests for these views.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to pass the json object to the Client.  Here's a simplest-case version of my code:

```
def test_ajax_call(self):
    c = Client()
    call_command('loadfixtures', 'temp-fixtures-1') #Custom command to populate the DB

    J = {
      some_info : {
        attr1 : "AAAA",
        attr2 : "BBBB",
        list_attr : [ "x", "y", "z" ]
      },
      more_info : { ... },
      info_list : [ 1, 22, 23, 24, 5, 26, 7 ]
    }

    J_string = json.dumps(J)
    response = c.post('/ajax/call/', data=J_string )
```

When I run the test, it fails with:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

How can I pass the JSON object in the Client.post method?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#django.test.client.Client.post) seems to imply that if you pass a `content_type` parameter to `client.post`, it will treat the `data` value as a document and POST it directly. So try this:

```
response = c.post('/ajax/call/', content_type='application/json', data=J_string)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for decoding the fine print in the documentation.  It never mentions json specifically, so it wasn't turning up in any of my searches.

Comment: Note that for this particular use case, the request.is_ajax() probably doesn't work.  So if you are using something like 'application/json' in request.META['CONTENT_TYPE'] to detect if the call is Ajax instead, Daniel's solution has the added benefit of properly setting the content type header.

Comment: This is the post info I receive when adding that content type: `<QueryDict: {u'{"info_list": [1, 22, 23, 24, 5, 26, 7], "some_info": {"list_attr": ["x", "y", "z"], "attr2": "BBBB", "attr1": "AAAA"}}': [u'']}>`, so all the data becomes the key, that doesn't seems right.

Comment: @Hassek you must not have dumped a json string like the question above. I was getting same issue until I did a `json.dumps(data)`

Comment: @Abe did you manage to test your ajax view? i.e. your were able to retrieve  data post from client in your view? I have open a post for an issue testing my ajax view so I would appreciate your kind help...