# How to set request.body in django Request factory post request?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

trying to set request.body in python unit test as

```
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.request = self.factory.get(reverse('get_associations'))
        self.request.user = self.auth_user
        self.request.body = json.dumps(self.post_data)
```

but it gives error:

```
self.request.body = json.dumps(self.post_data)
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

can anybody help me to fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802299/django-testing-post-based-views-with-json-objects), try this:

```
self.request = self.factory.get(reverse('get_associations'),
                                data=json.dumps(self.post_data),
                                content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: In our codebase, I had to override _mutable and set it manually.  No other apparent solution at the moment.