# Create a unit test using Django's test client post method passing parameters and requesting JSON from rest_framework

Tags: python, json, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I want to instantiate a `django.test.client.Client()` or `rest_framework.test.APIClient()`, POST a simple set of parameters, and request a JSON format response from a djangorestframework class-based view.

The documentation [suggests](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#making-requests) I just instantiate APIClient() and post with the parameter `format='json'`:

```
rest_framework.test import APIClient
apiclient = APIClient()
response = apiclient.post('/api/v1/model/1/run',
                          data=request_params, format='json')
```

However then my view (a DRF viewset custom method) does not receive the request parameters. Tracing this to the view, the POST parameters do make it to `request.data` as a dict, but `request.POST.items()` returns an empty list. When I use the code below to make a POST request over AJAX from a browser, `request.POST.items()` returns all the parameters correctly. It is only when using the unit test `APIClient()` `post()` method that the parameter values aren't in `request.POST.items()`.

If I use the `.get()` method of `APIClient()`, the request parameters are not in `request.data` when it reaches the view, but they are in `request.GET.items()`, passed down in `QUERY_STRING`. The values are moved from query string to the WSGIRequest GET QueryDict by ClientHandler.**call** in django.test.client line 115 `request = WSGIRequest(environ)` (Django 1.9.7). This doesn't seem to be happening for `APIClient()` `post()`.

I tried the following:

- Passing `json.dumps(request_params)` to the data parameter, but same response - my view doesn't see any parameters in the request ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802299/django-testing-post-based-views-with-json-objects)).
- Using the Django Client, passing `content_type='application/json'`, with and without json.dumps, but same response.
- Using Django Client, setting post **extra parameter to `HTTP_ACCEPT='application/json'` (with and without json.dumps) - same response.
- Initializing the Django Client with `HTTP_ACCEPT='application/json'` (with and without json.dumps) - same response.
- Leaving the `Accept` HTTP header, post's content_type parameter, and APIClient's format parameter undefined, and adding `{'format':'json'}` to the request_params - *which works for `Client.get` requests*, my code sees request parameters, but rest_framework returns HTML. The JSON rendered in this HTML shows the code is working correctly (returns status 202 and a polling URL, as it should).
- Appending `.json` to the URL in the unit test and leaving content type, etc, at their defaults, but I get `Not Found: /api/v1/model/1/run/.json` from get_response.

My code works fine accepting AJAX POST requests through the browser, and my unit tests were working fine when I was using client.get(). It is only the combination of using client.post() and needing JSON back that I cannot get working.

I extract the request values with:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form_values = ((key, value) for key, value in request.POST.items())
else:
    form_values = ((key, value) for key, value in request.GET.items())
```

The Javascript that sends the AJAX request, *that succeeds and returns JSON*, is as follows:

```
// Setup at the bottom of the HTML body
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
      data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}", format: "json" }
    });
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
            }
        }
    });
});

// Code that makes the request url=/api/v1/model/1/run, method=post 
// Only POST is permitted on the view method by decorator @detail_route(methods=['post']))
function run_model(event)
{
    var form = $(event.target);

    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: $("#" + form.attr('id')).serialize() + "&format=json&csrfmiddlewaretoken={{ csrf_token }}"
    })
    .done(function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        poll_instance(data.instance_id, data.model_id);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, status, err) {
        var status_div = $("." + construct_div_class("model", "div", jqXHR.responseJSON.model_id)).children("div.status");
        if (catch_ajax_error(status_div, failed_tries, jqXHR, status, err)) {
            setTimeout(run_model, 3000, event);
        };
    });

    event.preventDefault();
};
```

The Accept header was what got this working, format=json didn't work.

This is the receiving view:

```
class ModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def run(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Runs a model and redirects to the URL that will return the output results when ready.
        """
        try:
            instance_id = run_model(request, self.get_object().id)

        except ParameterValidationError as e:

        # ...    

        return Response(data={'instance_id': instance_id, 'model_id': self.get_object().id},
                        status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

The form, whose submit is tied to run_model() above:

```
<form method="POST" action="/api/v1/model/3/run/" id="model-form-3">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <tbody><tr>
            <th>
                Model
            </th>
            <th>
                Parameter
            </th>
            <th>
                Value
            </th>
        </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 Source source model of Composite (model #2)
             </td>
             <td>
                 GUI dim value in for POC model #89
             </td>
             <td>
                 <select name="5_77" id="5_77">
                        <option value="13">
                            Dimension description #17
                        </option>
                        <option value="14">
                            Dimension description #18
                        </option>
                </select>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 Source model of Composite (model #1)
             </td>
             <td>
                 Decimal GUI value in for POC model #64
             </td>
             <td>
                    <input name="4_52" id="4_52" value="123456789" type="text">
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 Second source model of Composite (model #3)
             </td>
             <td>
                 GUI dim value in for POC model #112
             </td>
             <td>
                 <select name="6_100" id="6_100">
                        <option value="16">
                            Dimension description #20
                        </option>

                        <option value="17">
                            Dimension description #21
                        </option>
                    </select>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 Dependent of Composite (model #0)
             </td>
             <td>
                 GUI dim value in for POC model #45
             </td>
             <td>
                 <select name="3_33" id="3_33">
                        <option value="7">
                            Dimension description #11
                        </option>
                        <option value="8">
                            Dimension description #12
                        </option>
                    </select>
             </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 Dependent of Composite (model #0)
             </td>
             <td>
                 Decimal GUI value in for POC model #43
             </td>
             <td>
                    <input name="3_31" id="3_31" value="123456789" type="text">
             </td>
         </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <input value="Run model" type="submit"><br><br>
</form>
```

I'm on Python 3.5, Django 1.9.7, djangorestframework 3.4.0 (also happened in 3.2.1), djangorestframework-xml 1.3.0, debugging in PyCharm 2016.1

Comment: Can you please show the js part that you're using to send data using ajax. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @mariodev good point, I've added the Javascript.

Comment: Not sure why are you using url query as data for ajax call. Can we se the receiving view as well please? From what you showed so far I think it's just not a proper ajax payload format...

Comment: I've added the view but I'm not sure I understand you. The Javascript part works fine, it is only the unit test that is having problems. The front-end submits a task to the server, the server creates a task and returns IDs that enable the browser to poll until the task is completed (hence the 202). (The HTML is rendered server-side, wrapped in JSON, and inserted into the DOM dynamically, I've pasted in the dynamically generated form, although not sure that's relevant here.)

Comment: I thought I'd made a different mistake but I hadn't. I run the tests successfully when using `apiclient.get(..., format='json')`, but my request parameters go missing when I do exactly the same test using `apiclient.post(..., format='json')`. The view works fine when accepting POST requests from the code in the question.

Comment: I think you are mixin up formdata post and JSON post. The JavaScript side clearly sends (manually, why?) `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, which it claims to be JSON (from `ajaxSetup()`). That part is probably parsed by django into `request.POST` (although it probably shouldn't parse, because of the content type mismatch). The test client sends JSON, which will not end up in `request.POST`, but rather (already decoded into a dictionary) in `request.data`. How does your [parser](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/) setup look like?

Comment: @dhke you are exactly right, that is exactly what I'm seeing. Would the correct implementation be to change my view to check `request.data`, and my jquery is incorrect somehow? I thought that a jquery POST over AJAX should be retrieved from request.POST, is this where I'm wrong?

Comment: I send the form data manually because it was the only way I could get my request values in `request.POST` in the Django view. I don't know any better! And there I was thinking these unit tests were wasting my time..

Comment: @Chris DRF is perfectly capable of parsing both JSON and form-encoded data when told to do so (see [parser documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/)). `request.POST` is bare django, while `request.data` is filled by DRF. JSON data will never end up in `request.data`, because bare django knows nothing about JSON posts. Since you are using AJAX anyway, it's probably best to change the JavaScript to do a JSON post (just pass a dictionary), keep `'format': 'json'` and rewrite the server to pull data from `request.data` ... unless you need file uploads, that is.

Comment: I'm still missing something obvious, sorry @dhke . Best way I can find of getting a form's values into a dictionary for passing as data over the $ajax call is `$(".form-selector").serializeArray().map(function(x){data[x.name] = x.value;});` I think this is why I ended up with my `.serialize()` cludge.

Comment: @Chris: I see. It's probably easier, if you just make the server accept  form-encoded data. Add `parser_classes = (JSONParser, FormParser)` to your view class and DRF will also `x-www-form-urlencoded` posts. The form fields will end up in `request.data`. Don't forget to remove the `format: 'json'`, though as you end up sending the wrong content type, otherwise. And, yeah, there's a [jquery plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), that does the dirty work for you

Comment: I think this is my dilemma - if I remove `format=json` DRF returns HTML, which is no good for the browser or unit test. So I *think* you're right that I need to send as JSON, because DRF seems to assume it should receive and return in the same format. (This question was looking in the wrong place.)

Comment: The solution I went for was to use `apiclient(...format='json')`, and to use the jquery plugin and `data: $("#" + form.attr('id')).formSerialize()` and add to my view `elif request.data: form_values = ((key, value) for key, value in request.data.items())` in my view. (My form to dictionary code doesn't work for radios, multi-selects, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the AJAX data is *supposed* to appear in `request.data`, and I was using the wrong approach to submit the data via AJAX from the browser. Django rest_framework (DRF) assumes that data from the request will be passed in the same format as data returned to the client - in this case JSON both ways. As it assumes that for an `Accept=application/json` request, incoming data will be in JSON format, it automatically parses it and populates `request.data` for you, and `request.GET` and `request.POST` are empty by the time the request reaches your DRF view.

To pass a form of data in the AJAX request I use the [jquery form plugin's](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) `.formSerialize()` method.

I did just have a `.map()` compile a dictionary from a form, but this won't work for radios and other instances where you might have several values for a single key/form id.

Credit for this answer should really go to @dhke, who pointed out my fundamental error. Although perhaps this question should be deleted.